# Carregamento dinâmico de componentes baseados em sua referência

Tags: angular

Galera, boa tarde.

Estou tendo o seguinte problema.

Dada uma estrutura:

```
[
   {
     title: "A",
     content: ComponentReference
   },
   {
     title: "B",
     content: ComponentReference
   },
]
```

Preciso carregar um  do Angular Material, de forma que cada ComponentReference, que são **referências** de componentes diferentes, precisam ser renderizados dentro de cada mat-tab.

Alguma ideia de como eu poderia fazer esse ComponentReference ser renderizado dentro da mat-tab?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido usando NgComponentOutlet.